# MSAL access token not refreshing -- "entry.trim not a function" error on acquireTokenSilent call

Tags: azure, vue.js, token, azure-ad-msal

I have been tasked with understanding why our Vue app keeps getting 401 errors for users after being active for 1 hour.  The access token seems to be valid and working fine for 1 hour after logging in, but after that point it does not refresh properly.  We are using vue-msal 3.2.0.  Tokens are being store in localStorage.

Here is our axios request interceptor

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async request => {
    // Find token in localstorage
    var tokenrespon = await store.dispatch('acquireToken', {
      scopes: ['user.read', 'offline_access'],
      getidtoken: true
    });
    var token = tokenrespon.Idtoken;
    request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return request;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

and here is the aqcuireToken call that gets called in the above piece:

```js
async acquireToken({ commit }, scopes = ['user.read'], getidtoken = false) {
  var msalinstance = new PublicClientApplication(state.msalConfig)

  if (!msalinstance) {
    return null
  }
  // Set scopes for token request
  const accessTokenRequest = {
    account: state.AzureLocalID,
    scopes: scopes
  }
  let tokenResp
  try {
    // 1. Try to acquire token silently
    tokenResp = await msalinstance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
    commit('setToken', tokenResp)
  } catch (err) {
    // 2. Silent process might have failed so try via popup
    tokenResp = await msalinstance.acquireTokenPopup(accessTokenRequest)
    commit('setToken', tokenResp)
  }

  // Just in case check, probably never triggers
  if (!tokenResp.accessToken) {
    commit('removeToken')
    throw new Error("### accessToken not found in response, that's bad")
  }
  if (getidtoken) {
    return tokenResp.idToken
  } else {
    return tokenResp.accessToken
  }
},
```

I'm getting `TypeError: entry.trim is not a function` on the acquireTokenSilent call in the try block.

I have changed the request interceptor to be async, it was not previously.  I also added the `offline_access` scope and passed that into the acquireToken but that doesnt seem to change anything.   Not sure if it is an issue with Azure/MSAL config or something in our code.

We would like for the app to auto renew the access token using the refresh token once this one hour period has been reached.